# how to pass blank to batch file as parameter

Tags: batch-file

I need to pass blank("" or " ") to a batch file as parameter.

I have to pass the runtime values to a url. My url is:

```
start iexplore http://example.com?emailAddress=%1&name=%2&phone=%3&dateofbirth=%4&hobby=%5&address=%6
```

Everything works fine if all parameters have some value, but if the value of any of the parameters is "" or " ", i.e., blank, the next non-blank value is assignment and the sequence is disordered.

Please help !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `%~x` instead of `%x` (where x is your parameter number)

This removes any enclosing quotes from the paramater, hence

```
echo parameter3=%~3
```

would show `parameter3=`

if you called this with `yourbatch one two "" four`

If you pass `"`<kbd>space</kbd>`"` as a parameter then this will show a space as `%~3` (which is a bit hard to see - try appending an obvious string)

In either case, if you use `%x` then you'd show enclosing quotes - either `""` or `" "` depending on which you passed in that position. You probably don't want quotes just there...

Answer (score 0):

just alt+0255 can be passed in batch example
a.bat

a="ÿ" echo "ÿ" set /p c="gg"

in here ÿ will be viewd as emptysace in batch when running ignore set /p c="gg" that just for making batch wait wait untill u press any value